# Css use color from inheriting color, into an other property

Tags: html, css

I want to use the color my color property gets from inheriting color in my background-color property.

```
.myclass {
     color: "inherit";
     background-color: {{somehow get value of color from color property}};
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
.myclass {
     color: "inherit";
     background-color: currentColor;
}
```

Comment: Daymn, i didnt actually expect css to have an answer to this, this works <3

Comment: Could you please choose it as accepted answer if it solved your problem, you are welcome :)

Comment: yes, stackover flow wants me to wait 5 minutes before i chose it as accepted answer

Comment: what if i want to inherit color's color into my background-color, while using a different color in color property? is that possible?

Comment: Maybe I did not understand your question well but in this case I would write the colors that I want to give for color and background-color seperately

Comment: my use case requires me to dynamically assign my background color with the value my color gets from inheriting color, while giving the color property a different color

Comment: It can be some work around solutions maybe but I do not know honestly because currentColor will always inherit from current color

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233041/discussion-between-evren-and-zothix).

Comment: Okay, messaged you there

Answer (score 2):

How about using `currentColor`? https://css-tricks.com/currentcolor/

An example:

```css
#outer {
  color: red;
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}

#inner {
  background: currentColor;
  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

You can use `currentColor` for other properties as well (e.g. for border, box-shadow, etc.).

```css
#outer {
  color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}

#inner {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px currentColor;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

As a side note:
If your use case is that you want to propagate some information to the children of an element, I'd suggest to also check out CSS Custom Properties, sometimes also called CSS Variables. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: obviously this works as well <3 thanks man

Comment: I am glad that my answer helps :-)